# How to solve the lag in a Get Endpoint ASP.Net API

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I have an Endpoint in my API that returns the number of orders conducted by a specific driver during the current week as well as the total earning they gained. The code I wrote works perfectly fine. However, it is proving to be slow with a large number of orders. How can I improve on the code to make it less time consuming.

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetWeeklyDriverReport(int id)
            {
                int mon = 0, tues = 0, wedn = 0, thurs = 0, fri = 0, sat = 0, sun = 0;
                int _mon = 0, _tues = 0, _wedn = 0, _thurs = 0, _fri = 0, _sat = 0, _sun = 0;
    
            DateTime givenDate = DateTime.Today;
            DateTime startOfWeek = givenDate.AddDays(-1 * (Convert.ToInt32(givenDate.DayOfWeek) - 1));
            DateTime endOfWeek = startOfWeek.AddDays(7);

            var report = new List<DailyReport>();

            var driver = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id.ToString());

            if(driver == null)
                return NotFound();

            var orders = await _unitOfWork.Orders.GetAll(v => v.DriverId == driver.Id, q => q.OrderByDescending(s => s.FinishedDate));

            orders = orders.Where(ob => startOfWeek <= ob.FinishedDate && ob.FinishedDate < endOfWeek).ToList();

            if (orders.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (var order in orders)
                {
                    var day = Enum.GetName(typeof(DayOfWeek), Convert.ToInt32(order.FinishedDate.DayOfWeek));

                    if (day == "Monday")
                    {
                        mon += 1;
                        _mon += Convert.ToInt32(order.PaymentAmount);
                    }
                    //I repeat this process for each day of the week
                }

                var monday = new DailyReport { Day = "Monday", Deliveries = mon, Earnings = _mon };
                var tuesday = new DailyReport { Day = "Tuesday", Deliveries = tues, Earnings = _tues };
                var wednesday = new DailyReport { Day = "Wednesday", Deliveries = wedn, Earnings = _wedn 
                
                report.Add(monday);
                report.Add(tuesday);
                report.Add(wednesday);
                //I repeat this process for each day of the week

                return Ok(report);
            }
            else
            {
                return NoContent();
            }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure all of thes tags are relevant? ASP.NET (.NET Framework), ASP.NET Core (.NET Core), and Visual Studio (the tool you use to author your code, that doesn't actually execute your code). I believe you're using ASP.NET Core, so I've removed the other irrelevant tags for you.

Comment: Does your database have an index on the users table for the user Id? Does your database have an index on the orders table for the driver Id? The database is likely to be the source of the slowness if it isn't optimized for the queries you're running.

Comment: What is taking long? Is it the `foreach` loop? Is it the database query? Is it the `order = order.Where(...)`?

Comment: You can definitely optimise all the queries and the `for..each` loop. I'd suggest placing some `Stopwatch` markers in there to see what exactly is taking so long. For example, you can collapse the Count and For...Each checks, they do the same thing and your orders is being instantiated and assigned a value, only to then be assigned another value making the first one irrelevant.

Comment: What is `order.FinishedDate`? Is it a normal `DateTime`? Because if so, there's no need to convert it to an integer, only to convert to a string to do equality checks, instead just use a [switch statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch)

Comment: Can you share the Order class? Besides, try to use the [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-5.0) class to determine the execution time (query data from database or loop the order and generate the report), then, we can according to the result to improve the performance.